# webpack dev server adds prefix to image name

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

webpack-dev-server is adding the prefix 'dist' to image file names, whereas webpack -p does not add the 'dist' prefix. I'm working through Petr Tichy's tutorials on youtube and I just don't see where the problem is in my `webpack.config.js` file. It's not adding the prefix to the other files, just the image file names.  Can you see what the problem is here?

```
    var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
       rules:  [
          {
            test: /\.scss$/, 
              use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
                publicPath: '/dist'
              })
          },
            {

              test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
              use: 'file-loader'
            }   
         ]
    },
     devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        stats: "errors-only",
        open: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'The Title',
        minify: { 
          collapseWhitespace: true
        },
        hash: true,
        template: './src/index.ejs', // Load a custom template (ejs by default see the FAQ for details)
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'app.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

Here's the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "thename",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "prod": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: As you have put , publicPath: '/dist', it will add the dist before every image path.. This is an expected behaviour.

Comment: @Ravi thank you. But why before every image path but not before the css for instance?  Why only the images?

Comment: Because, images are treated as assets... CSS are built after compiling SCSS/less. You can see the same behaviour even for fonts also. Also.. you must be importing these images inside SCSS, so textextract plugin gives you the capabilities to provide the public path..

Comment: @Ravi ah, ok that's helpful. So what's the point of using publicPath other than to add a prefix to images?

Comment: So the only reason to use publicPath in ExtractTextPlugin is to avoid the relative Path - while importing the assets.
 
Scenario : When you are using a background image for someRandomClass.

Now, webpack tries to bundle the resouce by looking at the url path.

But in some scenario - the resources are just available on prod server.

So, instead of give this publicPath config and tell the webpack to append the Absolute Path before the resources.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306822/webpack-url-file-loader-is-not-resolving-the-relative-path-of-url